# SQL Server CTE for Aggregating Costs at Each Level of Hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data

I can't figure out how to write a CTE that will roll up costs from a transaction table to a self-join table so that it will give me total costs at each level of the hierarchy. I've put together a very simple example to illustrate the problem.
Here are the DDL and Insert scripts so you can reproduce the issue, should you be so kind as to help me out:

```
CREATE TABLE [Items](
    [ItemId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [ItemName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [Transactions](
    [TransactionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [money] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TransactionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Items] ON 
GO
INSERT [Items] ([ItemId], [ParentId], [ItemName]) VALUES (1, NULL, N'Warehouse')
GO
INSERT [Items] ([ItemId], [ParentId], [ItemName]) VALUES (3, 1, N'Bin 1')
GO
INSERT [Items] ([ItemId], [ParentId], [ItemName]) VALUES (4, 1, N'Bin 2')
GO
INSERT [Items] ([ItemId], [ParentId], [ItemName]) VALUES (5, 3, N'Item 1.1')
GO
INSERT [Items] ([ItemId], [ParentId], [ItemName]) VALUES (6, 3, N'Item 1.2')
GO
INSERT [Items] ([ItemId], [ParentId], [ItemName]) VALUES (7, 4, N'Item 2.1')
GO
INSERT [Items] ([ItemId], [ParentId], [ItemName]) VALUES (8, 4, N'Item 2.2')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Items] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Transactions] ON 
GO
INSERT [Transactions] ([TransactionId], [ItemId], [Amount]) VALUES (1, 5, 10.0000)
GO
INSERT [Transactions] ([TransactionId], [ItemId], [Amount]) VALUES (2, 5, 10.0000)
GO
INSERT [Transactions] ([TransactionId], [ItemId], [Amount]) VALUES (3, 6, 10.0000)
GO
INSERT [Transactions] ([TransactionId], [ItemId], [Amount]) VALUES (4, 6, 10.0000)
GO
INSERT [Transactions] ([TransactionId], [ItemId], [Amount]) VALUES (5, 4, 10.0000)
GO
INSERT [Transactions] ([TransactionId], [ItemId], [Amount]) VALUES (6, 7, 10.0000)
GO
INSERT [Transactions] ([TransactionId], [ItemId], [Amount]) VALUES (7, 7, 10.0000)
GO
INSERT [Transactions] ([TransactionId], [ItemId], [Amount]) VALUES (8, 8, 10.0000)
GO
INSERT [Transactions] ([TransactionId], [ItemId], [Amount]) VALUES (9, 8, 10.0000)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Transactions] OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [Items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Items] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
REFERENCES [Items] ([ItemId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [Items] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Items]
GO
ALTER TABLE [Transactions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_Items] FOREIGN KEY([ItemId])
REFERENCES [Items] ([ItemId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [Transactions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_Items]
GO
```

Here is the CTE that I've been working on:

```
With cteAggregateCost
as  
(  
    select i.itemId, i.ParentId, t.Amount
    from Items i join Transactions t on i.ItemId = t.ItemId
union all
    select i.itemId, i.ParentId, t.Amount
    from Items i join cteAggregateCost c on i.ItemId = c.ParentId
    join Transactions t on i.ItemId = t.ItemId
)
select i.ParentId, i.ItemId, i.ItemName, sum(Amount) As AggregateCost
from Items i left join cteAggregateCost c on i.ItemId = c.ItemId
group by i.ParentId, i.ItemId, i.ItemName
```

This is the result I am getting:

[image: Bad Result]

And this is the result I am hoping to get:

[image: Hoped-for Result]

As you can see, all lines are working except the first two, that do not have a cost for the container, only their contained items.

Thanks so much for any direction you may be able to offer!

Comment: Where would those values come from? 90 and 40? For that combination of data `(itemid =1 and parentid = null)` and `(itemid=3, parentid = 1)`. In the example you have provided there are no matching values for those records in the `Transaction` table.

Comment: @Rigerta  `sum` up the children of the `ItemId`.  `ItemId` 1 is the parent for `ItemId` 3 and 4, which have totals of 40 and 50, which `sum` up to 90.  `ItemId` 3's total of 40 comes from the `sum` of children 5 and 6 of 20 each.  `ItemId` 4 is 50 because you need to include both children (`ItemId` 7 and 8) as well as the single transaction for `ItemId` 4 itself.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `recursive CTE` like this

```
;WITH temp AS 
(
   SELECT i.*, sum(isnull(t.Amount,0)) AS Amount 
   FROM @Items i
   LEFT JOIN @Transactions t ON t.ItemId = i.ItemId
   GROUP BY i.ItemId, i.ParentId, i.ItemName
)
,cteAggregateCost
as  
(  
   select i.ItemId, i.ItemId AS RootId, i.Amount  
   from temp i     
union all
   select i.ItemId, c.RootId, i.Amount 
   from cteAggregateCost c
   INNER JOIN temp i ON i.ParentId = c.ItemId
)
select i.*, ca.TotalAmount
from  @Items i 
CROSS APPLY 
(
   SELECT Sum(cac.Amount) AS TotalAmount
   FROM cteAggregateCost cac WHERE i.ItemId = cac.RootId
) ca
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/XMK96314

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, TriV. Your answer is brilliant! However, I did find a simpler answer posted by [Xi Jin on the SQL Server forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a46844d7-5152-43cb-839f-8052f1e12291/sql-server-cte-for-aggregating-costs-at-each-level-of-hierarchy?forum=transactsql). Here is his solution:

```
    With cteAggregateCost
    as  
    (  
        select  i.itemId as rootid,i.itemid, i.ParentId
        from Items i 
        union all
        select rootid, i.itemId, i.ParentId
        from Items i join cteAggregateCost c on i.ParentId = c.ItemId
    )

    select a.parentid, a.ItemId , a.ItemName , sum(t.Amount) As AggregateCost
    from items a
    left join cteAggregateCost i on a.itemid = i.rootid 
    left join Transactions t on i.ItemId = t.ItemId
    group by a.parentid, a.ItemId, a.ItemName
```

Both solutions give the same correct results that I was looking for when tested against a much larger dataset with many layers of hierarchical relationships. For me, Xi Lin's answer is easier to understand. I just couldn't work out how to add the rootID technique that preserved the values of the items that had no cost of their own and only had costs from child items.

Comment: The purpose of using RootId is take all child-nodes of *each* node in your table. It was done by recursive CTE and one thing left is `left join` to `transactions` to guarantee all items in left table exists. Your first query is not correct because inner join to `transactions` table. And `recursive CTE` does not allow using `left join`, so you must move it outer.

Comment: Thanks TriV. It makes perfect sense now that I see the final answer. I really appreciate your explanation.